What type of circuit breaker can I use for my Sylvania type qfp ? It is a 20 amp single pole breaker

Circuit breaker replacement for GTE Sylvania power box.

Can you provide us with photos of the existing breakers in the panel? I have a suspicion about what the correct replacement is, but want to verify things...

The directory is really messed up and should be redone. If nothing else, some items listed (range, dryer) are 240V double-breakers. Plus you need to know which breaker is truly "DO NOT USE" as that may be for safety reasons. A picture of the full panel will help.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Your concerns are entirely unfounded and irrelevant to the question being asked. 1. The label for space 18 is “Not in use” (not “DO NOT USE”) which is not concerning. 2. Gas appliances that use 120V only are a thing. There is no reason to assume that the dryer and stove must actually be using two breaker spaces each.

@nobody My concerns are based in the vast majority of situations. In addition to what I already noted, the main disconnect which must be a double breaker is listed as breaker 1. In fact, it is almost certainly a separate not-numbered breaker at the top, as shown in the diagram. And if it were a backfed branch breaker it would be 1/2, not just 1. But you are correct about 18 - I misread it.

I added a picture of the full panel. The weak breaker is the one at the very bottom. It's numbered 19 but is the last breaker at the very bottom.

It looks like you actually do have the first branch breaker (but really a double-breaker, as are several others, as expected) as a backfed main. If that's really correct, that's a 50A feed breaker for all this stuff???? That's absolutely crazy and points to either "never using much of the heat" or "50A breaker seriously overloaded but never trips".

I very rarely use any of the wall heaters as there is a gas fireplace in the dining room that heats the house pretty well. Thank you all for your help.

The QFP is the configuration of the main breaker, you won't find that in a 20A size. The match you are looking for a branch circuit is a Type Q.
Sorry, you'll find no good news here. GTE/Sylvania acquired Zinsco, then realized they bought a defective product line and dealed it off to T&B who orphaned it. There are a few 3rd party companies like Connecticut Electric that make replacements that can be used if the panel itself is in good shape, but bottom line is that panel has got to go.
You can read a fairly short summary of the design flaws on Wikipedia. Particularly note the line that says:

Even worse, it can cause the breaker's contacts to fuse together, thus
preventing the breaker from tripping even in an overcurrent situation,
thereby causing a potential fire hazard.

Edit: After seeing your edit adding picture we can see it is a ground fault, so like it says on the breaker that would be an HRGF20. I don't think you can buy a new breaker of this style. I stand by my comment about panel needing replacement.


Yeah, on second look, it's a Zinsco :/

You've got BIG problems:
Zinsco breakers
These are known problems. And I wouldn't be a bit surprised if you are already having problems and just don't know it, because:
50A Backfed Main
I originally thought that 1 - Main Disconnect on the list was a mistake, and that it actually referred to a true main breaker above all the branch breakers. But I don't see any wires on the main breaker, and the first branch breaker is 50A. So it looks to me like you have a 50A breaker feeding everything. That presents two possibilities, neither very good:

50A service and wires - That would mean that to upgrade to a modern, safe, panel you would need new feed wires. Which you might very well anyway.
Larger service and higher usage and 50A breaker doesn't trip - This is really, really scary. But with all those heaters and range and dryer and so on, it is quite possible.

If your usage does indeed go over 50A on a regular basis (at least in the winter) then this needs to get fixed ASAP. Why? Because a breaker nominally designed for 50A that doesn't trip could have a more severe actual failure instead. Which would not be pretty.
Breaker List is Totally Wrong
Look at the left side diagram: there are 40 spaces. Each space is a breaker - either a single breaker or half of a double-breaker. As is often the case, basically all your 30A or larger breakers are actually double-breakers. But each of those is only listed as one breaker in the list. I believe the correct list (sorry if I can't decode all the names correctly) is:
1/2 - Main Disconnect (50A x 2)
3/4 - Range (30A x 2)
5/6 - Dryer (30A x 2)
7/8 - Living Room Heater (20A x 2)
9/10 - Bedroom (?) Heater (30A x 2)
11 - Upstairs Bedroom (20A)
12 - South Wall Kitchen (20A)
13 - Garbage Disposal (20A)
14 - North Wall Kitchen (20A)
15 - Living Room (20A)
16 - Laundry & Hall (20A)
17 - Refrigerator & Stove Hood (20A)
18 - Downstairs Bedroom (20A)
19 - Living Room (20A)
20 - Washing Machine (20A)
21 - Bathroom Lights (20A)
22 - Not in Use
23/24 - Upstairs Heat (30A x 2) - note that I moved this because this is a 30A x 2 which makes sense for heat, and otherwise there are too many breakers - *it could be something else*
40 - Bath & Outside Recep

This is probably not 100% correct, but closer to reality than what is currently listed.
I think a full panel replacement is in your future.

Well, that sucks. Thank you for your response just the same.
